# Custom classes and views

Tags: python, django, class, django-views

I have set up the following custom class and am trying to output its contents into a Django view, however I keep hitting various Attribute and Type errors. I wondered if someone could point me in the right direction, please?

Custom class

```
from pickle import OBJ
from urllib.request import HTTPPasswordMgr
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import request

class Bloodcancer():

    def __init__(self, my_symptoms=None, my_causes=None, my_treatments=None):
        self.symptoms = my_symptoms
        self.causes = my_causes
        self.treatments = my_treatments

class AcuteMyeloidLeukemia(Bloodcancer):

    def my_symptoms():
        symptomatology = {
            tuple({'a': "pale appearance",'b': "weakness or feeling tired", 'c': "shortness of breath", 'd': "easy brusing or bleeding",'e': "petechiae which are flat, pinpoint spots under the skin caused by bleeding", 'f': "loss of weight", 'g': "loss of appetite", 'h': "fever", 'i': "frequent minor infection"}
            )
            }
        print (symptomatology)

    def my_causes(self):
        causes = ['age', 'being male', 'genes', 'environment', 'other bone marrow diseases']
        return render(request, 'Healthcare/Conditions/Blood/Causes.html', {{causes}})

    def my_treatments(self):
        treatments = ['induction therapy', 'consolidation therapy', 'chemotherapy', 'allogenic stem cell transplantation', 'central nervous system treatment', 'treatment of older and frail patients with AML', 'Treatment of refractory or relapsed AML', 'Supportive treatment']
        return render(request, 'Healthcare/Conditions/Blood/Treatments.html', {{treatments}})
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest, request
from django.urls import path
from Healthcare.Conditions.Blood.blood import AcuteMyeloidLeukemia as a

def symptoms_view(self):
    sample_set = a.my_symptoms()
    x = sample_set['b'].get()
    return render('Symptoms.html', {xx})
```

urls.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from Healthcare import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Healthcare/Conditions/Blood/Symptoms/', views.symptoms_view)
]
```

[image: First Error]

[image: Second Error]

[image: Third Error]

Comment: Please improve your question by providing a [mre]. Don't just slap a bunch of code down and say "I get some errors from this, [i.e. find it for me]".

Comment: Hi, I think the issue is that when I run the class 

print(AcuteMyeloidLeukemia(Bloodcancer).my_symptoms)

It returns an object rather than the string I have typed in - any ideas on how to convert?

<bound method AcuteMyeloidLeukemia.my_symptoms of <__main__.AcuteMyeloidLeukemia object at 0x00000257C41E9550>>

Comment: you need to call the my_symptoms method by adding parentheses after the name `print(AcuteMyeloidLeukemia(Bloodcancer).my_symptoms())`

Comment: This is what I've been doing, but then it comes up saying that the object needs to be a string. I've tried converting to a string using a tuple but still getting the same error (reference error 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I skimmed your code and I figured out, you had some OOP problems:
First of all you have to make an instance from the `AcuteMyeloidLeukemia` class then you can use the `my_symptoms` method, and print the values in it, the other thing you have to change is to return the `symptomatology` in the method if not you cant print the values. Instead of html file I used `HttpResponse` to print out the result and the result is:

> weakness or feeling tired

Custom class: change the `AcuteMyeloidLeukemia` class and the `my_symptoms` method like this and don't forget to write self in the parentheses:

```
class AcuteMyeloidLeukemia(Bloodcancer):
    def my_symptoms(self):
        symptomatology = {
            'a': "pale appearance", 'b': "weakness or feeling tired", 'c': "shortness of breath", 'd': "easy brusing or bleeding",'e': "petechiae which are flat, pinpoint spots under the skin caused by bleeding", 'f': "loss of weight", 'g': "loss of appetite", 'h': "fever", 'i': "frequent minor infection"
            }
        return symptomatology
```

view.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .custom import AcuteMyeloidLeukemia as a


def symptoms_view(request):
    sample_set = a()
    x = sample_set.my_symptoms()
    print(x)
    # return render('Symptoms.html', {"x": x})
    return render(request, "doctor/symptoms.html",  context={"x": x})
```

urls.py : no change in this file

html file : to render html file you can import render and you should pass the request to it the next parameter is where the file is located, then context is our dict and I used your own html file to display the information , you can read more about rendering templates in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>the display page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border='1'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for column in x.keys %}
                <th>{{ column }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        {% for col in x.values%}
                <td>{{ col }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, much appreciated - it mostly works! Just the only thing I need to better understand is printing rows of data contained in the dictionary? At the moment following the above code either prints out just one item of data, or everything with no spaces. Would be grateful if you could kindly clarify the python code necessary to populate a HTML file.

Comment: @NeilFaulkner  i edited my answer based on what you asked for if it was helpful vote up and approve the answer